# Why can't other players interact with things around spawn when I make myself OP?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

When I'm opped on my private server other players cannot interact with certain things like chests and breaking blocks around spawn. When I de-op myself they can. So, what's causing this issue other than the fact that I'm OP?

Comment: That sounds like spawn protection, but... no idea why it's acting weird and allowing them when you de-op yourself.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As suspected by @Codingale, this is indeed spawn protection. From going through some decompiled Minecraft code, I gathered that a player is allowed to build at the spawn point of a world if:

- The world is not "dimension 0", i.e. it is a nether or end world.
- The list of OPs is empty.
- The player is OP.
- `spawn-protection` is set to 0 or less in your server config.
- The block is outside the spawn radius set in your server config.

As per that list and assuming you are the only OP on the server, de-oping yourself will cause the spawn protection to be bypassed.

If you don't like spawn protection, you can disable it by setting

```
spawn-protection=0
```

in your `server.properties`.

Note that [the Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Server.properties#Minecraft_server_properties) claims the following on `spawn-protection`:

> Setting this to 0 will not disable spawn protection. 0 will protect the single block at the spawn point.

However, this is not true. There is an explicit check in the code for that value and I've verified that setting it to `0` does indeed disable spawn protection for versions at least as far back as 1.8.

Comment: That totally makes sense. I didn't even think to check if there was any spawn protection or how it would be applied. :)